# The image overlay is stuck at the bottom of the image and is not moving when the user hovers over

Tags: html, css

I´m trying to overlay images with a description and when the user hovers the mouse over the overlay it will move down and show the photo that is underneath.

However the overlays seem to be stuck like this. With what looks like the overlays stuck to the bottom adn when you hover the mouse nothing happens. [image: overlay not working]

please excuse the images they´re just a random photo.

my html looks like this

```
<div class="Portfolio_container">
    <div class="Portfolio">
        <div class="section group">
            <div class="col span_1_of_3">
              <img src="Images/Dundee.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="image">
              <div class="overlay">
                <div class="text">Hello World</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col span_1_of_3">
                <img src="Images/Dundee.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="image">
                 <div class="overlay">
                   <div class="text">Hello World</div>
                 </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col span_1_of_3">
                <img src="Images/Dundee.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="image">
                <div class="overlay">
                    <div class="text">Hello World</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my CSS

```
.Portfolio_container {           
  background-color: #847470;     /* colour of the whole portfolio page */
}




.Portfolio {               /* keeps the examples in the middle with the background colour matching the container that surounds it*/
  width: auto;
  margin-right: 5%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  background-color: #847470;
}




/*  SECTIONS  */
.section {
  clear: both;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

/*  COLUMN SETUP  */
.col {
  display: block;
  float:left;
  margin: 1% 0 1% 2%;
}
.col:first-child { margin-left: 0; }

/*  GROUPING  */
.group:before,
.group:after { content:""; display:table; }
.group:after { clear:both;}
.group { zoom:1; /* For IE 6/7 */ }

/*  GRID OF THREE  */
.span_3_of_3 { width: 100%; }
.span_2_of_3 { width: 66%; }
.span_1_of_3 { width: 32%; }

/*  GO FULL WIDTH BELOW 480 PIXELS */
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .col {  margin: 1% 0 1% 0%; }
  .span_3_of_3, .span_2_of_3, .span_1_of_3 { width: 100%; }
}

.span_1_of_3 {
  height: 100%;
}

.image {
  max-width: 100%;     /* keeps the portfolio images within their divs */
  max-height: 100%;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}


.overlay {

  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #008CBA;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: .5s ease;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.span_1_of_3:hover .overlay {
  height: 0%;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please create snippets here for compilation your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution.

```
.span_1_of_3 {
    height: auto;
    position: relative; 
}
```

I had to make the div that was containing the overlays to have a relative position. Hopes this helps anyone who has this problem.